# How To add values from database column to a ComboBox without repetition?

Tags: sql-server, combobox, vb.net-2010

I have a column in database which has values like Good,Bad and May Be. There are like 200 rows which has like 20 rows with Value Good, 50 with Bad and so on, I am able to load the values from database to a comboBox but every values(200) are displayed in combobox , how to avoid repetition. I have added the code I used.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'CREATE OBJECT CONNECTION
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection

    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "server=(local)\sqlexpress;database=trial;integrated security=true"
        .Open()
    End With

    'CREATE OBJECT DATA TABLE AND DATA ADAPTER
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select kode,nama from warna order by kode", cn)

    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With ComboBox1
            .Items.Clear() 'CLEAR ITEMS COMBOBOX
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                'ADD ITEMS TO COMBOBOX
                .Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item("kode") & " - " & dt.Rows(i).Item("nama"))
            Next
            'CLEAR TEXT COMBOBOX
            .Text = Nothing
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With
    End If

    'CLEAR ALL OBJECT AND MEMORY
    With cn
        .Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    cn = Nothing
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
    da.Dispose()
    da = Nothing

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

while populating data in SQLAdapter use DISTINCT keyword:

```
select distinct kode,nama from warna order by kode
```

Above line you can use when you have duplicates in DB in Kode and nama combination.